# Как сделать мгновенное перемещение в Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть игра про то, как игрок едет на машине и сбивает зомби
Как сделать так, чтобы зомби при столкновении с машиной мгновенно перемещался в определенное место (например на координаты X 3.5 Y 2)

Может там скините скрипт который это будет делать, там добавить коллайдер с Is trigger надо

Comment: Вам нужна телепортация?

Comment: Да, типа того
(15 символов)

Answer (score 0):

Создайте  тэг zombie и присвойте его объекту, которого нужно телепортировать.

Далее повесьте этот скрипт на объект, который должен соприкосаться с зомби, после чего в инспекторе, в переменную _posTp укажите координаты, куда должен быть перемещён зомби

```
 public Vector3 _posTp;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collision other)
{
if(other.gameobject.tag == "zombie")
{
    other.gameobject.position= _posTp;
}
}
```